# css - why are my images overlapping?

Tags: css, html, overlapping

If you can to section "Equipe" on my website http://goo.gl/ok43H, you will see that the avatar pictures are overlapping vertically and I would like to have at least 10px btw each one.
What is the issue and how can I fix this?
Many thanks!

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome & Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.equipe-bio {
padding: 0 0 0 110px;
position: relative;
width: 50%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

You can replace `margin-bottom: 24px;` with any amount of pixels you wish, but this will create space in between the images.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple of things:

.equip-bio needs { overflow:hidden; margin-top:25px; }

Take off position:absolute; on each image, and instead give it float:left;
The paragraphs that are all part of each image, group them into a  giving it also a float:left; (and most likely some margin-left also).

That should fix it for you!

Comment: Thanks, actually I think that I will use margin-bottom:30px, seems to be working fine! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add the `min-height` property to the main `equipe-bio` element. I tried `min-height: 100px;` and the result was fine. Whatever the content in the `p` tags, or however short the bio is, the box will never shrink below 100 pixels high.